# Установка Ubuntu на разные диски

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

Имеется SSD и HDD, хочу поставить корневой каталог на SSD, домашний оставить нетронутым на HDD. Это приемлемо?
Теперь подробней.
Сейчас:
ssd: 100гб, винда (10 гб свободно, могу еще наосвобождать гигов 10-20 и отрезать для корнового каталога линукса)
hdd: 1) линукс - и корень, и home. Система полетела, исправлять не смогу как. Плюс корню мало места изначально дал - так что давно пора исправлять это дело, а тут и повод есть.

2) хранилище, ntfs. Доступно с обеих ОС
Мой план - снести корневой каталог линукса и создать его уже на SSD. Оставив имеющийся home. Это адекватно будет работать?

И да, сколько нужно памяти дать корневому? А то беда с этим имеется, даже не представляю.

Comment: линукс на hdd тоже быстро работает.  читайте минимаотные требования для ОС, чтобы понять сколько вам нужно место. не забудьте, что /var и /opt разделы могут много весить в будущем

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал потратить пару вечеров на (попытку) восстановления. Узнаете много интересного (не шутка).